# Evaluate boolean algebra expression for all binary numbers on a calculator

Tags: permutations, binary, calculator

Calculator: Casio fx-100AU PLUS

I have typed a boolean algebra expression in the `BASE-N` mode, which performs calculations on variables A, B, C, etc.

I am using the calculator to write a truth table, containing all binary numbers with a certain number of digits. For example:

```
A B C  Z

0 0 0  0
0 0 1  0
0 1 0  0
0 1 1  0
1 0 0  0
1 0 1  0
1 1 0  0
1 1 1  0
```

However, using `STO` to change the variables each time is quite time consuming.

Is there an approach where all binary numbers (in a certain range) can be evaluated? No specific method (ie variables) needs to be used, anything that works even slightly well would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Can the calculator convert from base 10 to base 2? Can it make a for loop?

Comment: @CyclotomicField The calculator can convert to binary, but can't execute scripts.

Comment: If you can't make a loop then I can't see any way to reduce your workload.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I had the idea of putting an entire number into one variable, and pull individual digits out for use in the calculations. This way I would simply need to add 1 to the number each time. However, there seems to be no way of doing this. Basically I'm looking for another alternate method like this one.